# Is it possible to force a class to be instantiated by singleton-only

Tags: c++, singleton

When I code with C++11, I usually use the design pattern Singleton. Here is how I design my Singleton:

```
template<typename T>
class Singleton {
private:
    Singleton() = default;
    ~Singleton() = default;
public:
    static T * GetInstance() {
        static T t;
        return &t;
    }
    Singleton(const Singleton &) = delete;
    Singleton(Singleton &&) = delete;
    Singleton & operator=(const Singleton &) = delete;
    Singleton & operator=(Singleton &&) = delete;
};
```

Then, we can define any class we want, such as `class Test{};`, and `Singleton<Test>::GetInstance();` will generate an object.

Everything works fine.

However, today I'm thinking that `class Test{};` could get rid of the limitation. I mean, even though I defined the class `Singletion<T>`, but other developers can define their classes, such as `Test`, and do NOT use the `Singleton`, so they can generate many objects if they want. But what I want is that if you decide to define a class, which should be singleton, you can't generate objects by calling constructors, but only by calling `Singleton<Test>::GetInstance()`.

In a word, I want to get this:

```
Test t;  // compile error
Test *p = Singleton<Test>::GetInstance(); // OK
```

To do so, I've tried some tricky method, for example, I make the class `Test` to inherit `Singleton<Test>`:

```
class Test : public Singleton<Test> {
public:
    Test() : Singleton<Test>() {}
};
```

So if you are defining a class, which should be singleton, you inherit the class `Singleton` and now your class can't generate any other objects by calling constructor. But it's not working as the constructor of `Singleton` is private. But if I write `friend T;` in the class `Singleton`, `Test t;` would become legal...

It seems that I can not force the class user to construct an object only by Singleton.

Can someone help me? Or telling me that I'm doing something impossible...

Comment: Have you tried making the constructors .private and making the Singleton its friend?

Comment: @StewartSmith Sorry I haven't made it clear. My need is that the class `Test` can define its class whatever he wants, but if he write a public constructor and `Test t;`, he should get an error. If I must tell the `Test` developer that "hey, you MUST define your constructor private", this is not what I want.

Comment: you can make constructor protected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CRTP pattern to achieve this

```
template <class T>
class Singleton {
public:
    Singleton& operator = (const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator = (Singleton&&)      = delete;

    static T& get_instance() {
        if(!instance)
            instance = new T_Instance;
        return *instance;
    }

protected:
    Singleton() {}

private:
    struct T_Instance : public T {
        T_Instance() : T() {}
    };

    static inline T* instance = nullptr;
};

class Example : public Singleton<Example> {
protected:
    Example() {}
};

int main()
{
    auto& test = Example::get_instance();
    Example e; // this will give you error
}
```

Comment: Note:  this is a leaky singleton.  It will leak the object at program termination.  That is sometimes acceptable to do (in my experience, *often times* it is acceptable to do).  Also the `get_instance` is not thread safe for the constructor if called in a race condition situation, which may be an issue for some scenarios, or just fine for other scenarios.

Comment: @Eljay After C++11, `get_instance` should be thread safe because of memory model.

Comment: @Yves • `if (!instance) instance = new T_Instance;` is not thread safe.